# I want my username and password to be encrypt in user login form?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I used the Pubkey Encrypt module with all dependencies Key, Encrypt and Encrypt PHPSecLib Encryption.

I configured with openssl in pubkey encrypt settings. With the help of field encrypt settings, i configure content type fields encrypt and stored in DB too(Encrypted) like video demo shown in pubkey encrypt.

But when i am checking over in tamper data tool the post parameter value of name and pass shows only the plain text -> Not encrypted.

So i need the suggestions to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour and I see no clear advantages on doing this client-side. If you want to protect confidential data (such as passwords) you should be using HTTPS.

This way, the data cannot be tampered with in-transit. Obviously you can still change it with browser development tools but if you are worried about the client being compromised then you already lost.

TL;DR: Use HTTPS on your server ;)

Comment: Our project in end of development, we were been working in our localhost. If we complete encryption of user and password in post parameter(field all encrypted->pending name and pass), we plan to host. Suggest any other module support for this method.